# react app cors error in backend connection

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors

I have troubles with CORS error.

I am developing a react app with create-react-app.

I am using axios to fetch data from BE but when I try to fetch I got cors error in chrome:

[image]

I tried to disable CORS policy in chrome but nothing is working.
Is very strange because the `login` route works while the other routes that need a `session` in header are not working. I tried also to call them through command line CURL and they work as expected.

With the curl command line I dumped the response header and I got:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 13:22:07 GMT
```

My frontend is in `http://localhost:3000` while the backend is in another domain on internet.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you are using express.js then just install cors module  import it like const cors=require("cors")and add  app.use(cors()) to your main server file

Comment: *I got cors error in chrome.* What's the error message? Does the preflight request succeed?

Comment: I attached chrome error

Comment: @Wolfetto There must be some error message in the Console tab. That's what's of interest here.

Comment: `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing` in preflight

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem enabling (in BE part) the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

Adding these, the preflight calls succeded and I was able to fetch the API

Answer (score -1):

You could either proxy the backend or request the backend to add CORS headers, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`,
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: With curl from command line I dump the HEADER server response:
`HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 13:22:07 GMT`

Comment: @Wolfetto you need the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header if your request include header other than `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Type`. Check this list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests

Comment: Adding to Tony Yip: I think you need to add those Access-Control-Allow-Headers in your server setup for preflight requests. With nginx there is an example https://dariuscoder.com/2021/09/16/how-to-debug-cors/